# $\iiint_{|x| + |y| + |z| > 1} \frac{1}{|x|^p + |y|^q + |z|^r}dxdydz$

Tags: multiple-integral

Could you help me to solve this very complicated problem? I don't know how to start.
$$\iiint_{|x| + |y| + |z| > 1} \frac{1}{|x|^p + |y|^q + |z|^r}dxdydz, p>0, q>0,r>0$$

Comment: I would start by trying it in two dimensions first.  See if that provides insight.

Comment: I have a good idea where to start.  Not sure where it goes.  The region is all of space excluding an octohedron around the origin.  The region and the function is symmetric such that you can evaluate just the first octant and multiply by 8.  The substitution u = x+y+z, simplify the region of integration, but might not simplify the integral itself.  The integral will definately not converge for values of p,q,r <1 and possibly for lager values.